# Passing data variable to function environmental variable as object or string

Tags: r, dplyr

Take this toy function - just a wrapper around `dplyr::select`:

```
select_col <- function(df, chosen_col) {
  
  if(is.character(enquo(chosen_col))){
    df %>%
      select(all_of(chosen_col))
  } else {
  df %>%
    select({{ chosen_col }})
  }
}
```

What it does is allows the selection of a column passed to `chosen_col`, regardless of whether that column is presented as a data variable masked as an environmental variable or a string masked as an environmental variable.

Both of these return the same thing:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select_col(chosen_col = mpg) %>% 
  head(2)
              mpg
Mazda RX4      21
Mazda RX4 Wag  21

mtcars %>% 
  select_col(chosen_col = "mpg") %>% 
  head(2)
              mpg
Mazda RX4      21
Mazda RX4 Wag  21
```

While `select_col` works, what I want is something more like this **doesn't work**:

```
select_col_desired <- function(df, chosen_col) {
  
  if(is.character(enquo(chosen_col))){
    chosen_col <- convert_to_env_variable(chosen_col)
  }

    df %>%
      select({{ chosen_col }})
}
```

What can I use in place of the non-existent function `convert_to_env_variable`such that `select_col_desired` returns the same things as `select_col`?

I am aware that `select` does this already outside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1: Single Column

If you truly want something like `convert_to_env_variable()`, you can just use `rlang::enquo()` to begin with, and skip the conditional.

```
select_col_desired <- function(df, chosen_col) {
    
    chosen_col <- enquo(chosen_col)
    
    df %>%
        select(!!chosen_col)
}
```

Heck, you could just skip the `enquo()` and `!!` altogether:

```
select_col_desired <- function(df, chosen_col) {
    df %>%
        select({{ chosen_col }})
}
```

This is because the "curly-curly" operator [`{{`](https://rdrr.io/cran/rlang/man/nse-force.html) first captures the argument passed to `chosen_col` and immediately defuses it as an expression; before substituting the result in its own place, here to be evaluated as a [data-variable](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data-and-env-variables) in the context of `df`.

### Result

Either way, you'll get this:

```
# With column as unquoted symbol.
mtcars %>% 
  select_col_desired(chosen_col = mpg) %>% 
  head(2)

#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21


# With column as string.
mtcars %>% 
  select_col_desired(chosen_col = "mpg") %>% 
  head(2)

#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
```

## Solution 2: Arbitrary Selection

For a more general solution, you could simply pass your columns as `...` to [`select()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html):

```
select_any_desired <- function(df, ...) {
  df %>% select(...)
}
```

### Result

```
# With column as unquoted symbol.
mtcars %>% 
  select_col_desired(mpg) %>% 
  head(2)

#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21


# With column as string.
mtcars %>% 
  select_col_desired("mpg") %>% 
  head(2)

#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
```

## Note

If you're writing a package, you'll naturally need to `@import` or qualify functions like [`rlang::enquo()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/enquo.html) and [`` magrittr:`%>%`() ``](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) and [`dplyr::select()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html); rather than using `library()`.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: get the name for the variable

This is done via `as.character(substitute(chosen_col))` and we also want to save it for step 2.

```r
varname <- as.character(substitute(chosen_col))
```

### Step 2: assign to a different environment

Assignment can be done using `assign(x, value, envir=parent.frame())`. Here it is essential to use `parent.frame()` as assigning environment since we want to assign outside of the function and default behavior is to assign to current environment. Another option here would be to assign to the global environment with `envir=globalenv`.

This leads us to

```r
assign(varname, x, envir=parent.frame())
```

where `x` is containing everything we want to assign. Read this as `varname <- x`.

### Putting both steps

```r
select_col <- function(df, chosen_col) {
    if(is.character(enquo(chosen_col))){
        x <- df %>%
            select(all_of(chosen_col))
    } else {
        x <- df %>%
            select({{ chosen_col }})
    }
    varname <- as.character(substitute(chosen_col))
    assign(varname, x, envir=parent.frame())
    x
}

select_col(mtcars, "mpg") %>% head(2)
#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
head(mpg, 2)
#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
rm(mpg)

select_col(mtcars, mpg) %>% head(2)
#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
head(mpg, 2)
#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
```